# how can we bold the word before colon like aaaaa bb ccc need to be bold in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, split, jsx

The regex is splitting string on word before colon, i am trying to bold the word before colon like aaaaa bb ccc need to be bold

```
str = "aaaaa: lorem ipsum bb: do lor sit amet ccc: no pro movet"
regex = / (?=\w+:)/g

splitString = str.split(regex)

console.log(splitString)
```

output of the above code is:

```
[
  "aaaaa: lorem ipsum",
  "bb: do lor sit amet",
  "ccc: no pro movet"
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "bold"? What is the output you need?

Comment: `str.replace(/\w+(?=:)/g, '<b>$&</b>')`?

Comment: Actually the string that is stored in str is splitted on the basis of reg exp, the output i needed is the same that is showed above that i am already getting, i just want the words before : to be bold or highlighted in jsx

Comment: as the array index 0 contains aaaaa: lorem ipsum so i want word before colon to be bold in each index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
var Component = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var text = this.props.text.split(/\s+(?=\w+:)/).map((address, index) =>
            <p key={index}>{ address.split(/(?=:)/).map((x,i)=> i===0 ? <b key={i}>{x}</b> : x) } </p> );
        
        return <div className="text">{text}</div>;
    }
});

var text = 'aaaaa: lorem ipsum bb: do lor sit amet ccc: no pro movet';
ReactDOM.render(
    <Component text={text} />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.0/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@0.14.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

*Details*:

- `.split(/\s+(?=\w+:)/)` - splits the `str` string with one or more whitespace chars that are directly followed with 1+ word chars and then a `:` char
- `.map((address, index) => <p key={index}>{ address.split(/(?=:)/).map((x,i)=> i===0 ? <b key={i}>{x}</b> : x) } </p> )` - takes each split and assigns its value to `address` and index to `index`, wraps the item with `<p key=index>` / `</p>` and modifies the item the way explained below...
- `address.split(/(?=:)/).map((x,i)=> i===0 ? <b key={i}>{x}</b> : x)` - each address string is split at the location right before a `:` char, and all even occurrences are wrapped with `<b>` tag, odd ones are kept as is.

Note that the `key` attribute is necessary for React to be able to handle minimal DOM changes, see [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28329382/3832970).

Answer (score 2):

Just modifying AnanthDev's answer to use `replace` which I think OP is trying to use.

```js
const str = "aaaaa: lorem ipsum bb: do lor sit amet ccc: no pro movet";

const boldArr = str.replace(/(\b[^\s]+)(:)/g, `\n${'$1'.bold()}$2`).split('\n').filter(x => x).map(x => x.trim());
console.log(boldArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to splitting, you can match with 2 capture groups (denoted as `m[1]` and `m[2]` in the example code) and make the first group bold in the callback from [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
(\w+)(:.*?)(?=\s+\w+:|$)
```

- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word chars in group 1
- `(:.*?)` Capture `:` and as least as possible chars in group 2
- `(?=\s+\w+:|$)` Positive lookahead, assert 1+ word chars followed by `:` or the end of the string to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FsAkud/1).

```js
const regex = /(\w+)(:.*?)(?=\s+\w+:|$)/g
str = "aaaaa: lorem ipsum bb: do lor sit amet ccc: no pro movet"
str = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => `<b>${m[1]}</b>${m[2]}`);
console.log(str);
```